# Query Validation on a database value using c#

Tags: c#, database, validation, entity-framework-6, dynamic-queries

I have a web application in c# that utilizes two databases. one database has employee numbers titled Employees, and the second database will store the application users that is more specific titled Users. what i am trying to do is validate that the number the user is inputting in a textbox is in the employees database so i know the person exists and then i want to add it to the users database, from there i want to also validate that the person doesn't already exist in the database. i have the logic in my head but i can't quite write up the code from my service class. also would like to point out i am using entity framework 6. any help would be great.

Comment: Sounds like you already know what you need to do: 1. Query the Employees DB and validate that it exists. 2. Query the Users DB and see if it exists there. 3. If not, then Insert it. What specifically are you having trouble with? Have you made attempts but it's not working? If so, show what you've tried.

Comment: i don't know what code to use, for example what my checks/loops should look like or my queries. just looking for quick examples that i can build off of. everywhere i look doesn't give this specific type of example. i have the thought process but don't know how to execute it in code.

Comment: i know what i need to do, i don't know how to do it

Comment: Do you have *anything* yet? Have you created models for EF, created the database, written the service calls, created the web site, etc.? Or, maybe you need to be more specific with your question. It sounds like you're asking for help with *everything*, which is way too broad to answer here. Have a look [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to get started.